# Do Golden Pothos need a day/night cycle?

Tags: houseplants, sunlight, office-gardening

My office has quite a few Golden Pothos and they are beautiful! I am wondering: how many hours of light do these plants need per day in an indoor environment? To go along with that I know that some plants need periods of darkness – do pothos require darkness each day?

As it may be of interest: there is no natural light for these plants at all. It is 100% artificial lighting.

Comment: What kind of artificial light is it? Fluorescent?

Answer (score 4):

Pothos generally like a bright or well lit spot, but not sunlight. They will grow in lower light levels, but those varieties with variegated leaves will lose the variegation in low light situations. On the assumption you want one at home, if you can find a spot for it reasonably close to a window where the sun doesn't reach it, it should be fine - its a relatively easy houseplant to grow. As for 'requiring darkness', in a normal home environment, supplying darkness isn't an issue - the lights aren't on at night, and even if one or two were, they're not gro lights, so shouldn't make much impact. Preferred temperature range is average, but not lower than 50-55 deg. F, mist leaves a couple of times a week in a heated environment. Can be grown up a moss pole or support, or as a trailing plant.

UPDATED ANSWER:

I don't know, is the answer, sorry! Maybe someone else does, but I can tell you that I have one of these and where it is, it's never in complete darkness - where I live is lit up like a Christmas tree year round outsid, all night, (not my choice), and even I don't need the lights on unless I'm cooking or reading. And the plant is fine, growing well....

Comment: As mentioned in my question this is in an office. The office has some lights which never turn off for safety reasons. So there is reduced lighting at night but these plants would never actually have normal darkness. Do pothos need a "night-time" cycle?

Comment: @levi morrison can you could edit your question to ask:  Do pothos need a "night-time/dark" cycle?

Comment: @LeviMorrison - see update in answer.